# Is there a way for multiple threads to sequentially access a list of shared resources?

Tags: java, multithreading

Is there a way for multiple threads to sequentially access a list of shared resources, I have two threads t1 and t2 and I want to access a list of objects based on a condition, also I want each thread to process only once before allowing other threads.

class items(int itemid, String itemname, int priority)

Sample input:

```
[ 123,"item1", 8 ], [124, "item2", 2], [125, "item3", 5 ], [126,"item4", 3]
```

expected output:

```
Thread1: Processing Item - 123, priority - 8,
Thread2: Processing Item - 125, priority - 5,
Thread1: Processing Item - 126, priority - 3,
Thread2: Processing Item - 124, priority - 2,
```

Tried using a priority queue with synchronization, but could not access the list of objects sequentially.

```
public class Items implements Comparable<Items>{
private int itemID;
private String itemname;
private int priority;

public Items(int itemID, String itemname, int priority)
{
    this.itemID = itemID;
    this.itemname = itemname;
    this.priority = priority;
}
public int getItemID() {
    return itemID;
}


public void setItemID(int itemID) {
    this.itemID = itemID;
}


public String getItemname() {
    return itemname;
}


public void setItemname(String itemname) {
    this.itemname = itemname;
}


public int getPriority() {
    return priority;
}


public void setPriority(int priority) {
    this.priority = priority;
}


@Override
public int compareTo(Items item) {

    return item.priority > this.priority ? 1 : item.priority < this.priority ? -1 :0;
}

}
package multithreading;

import java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue;

public class itemsImpl {

    private static PriorityBlockingQueue<Items> priorityQueue;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        priorityQueue = new PriorityBlockingQueue<Items>();

        priorityQueue.add(new Items( 123,"item1", 8));
        priorityQueue.add(new Items( 124, "item2", 2));
        priorityQueue.add(new Items( 125, "item3", 5));
        priorityQueue.add(new Items( 126,"item4", 3));

        itemsImpl impl = new itemsImpl();

        Thread t1 = new Thread( new Runnable(){
        public void run()
        {
            try {
                impl.pollQueue(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }});

        Thread t2 = new Thread( () -> {
            try {
                impl.pollQueue(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } );
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        }


    private void pollQueue(String name) throws InterruptedException
    {   
        while(priorityQueue.size()>0)
        {
            synchronized(this)
            {   
                    Items i = priorityQueue.poll();
                    System.out.println(name +": Items Processsing - " + i.getItemID() + ", priority - " + i.getPriority());
                    Thread.sleep(100);
            }

        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please add the actual output also?

Comment: Refer Expected Output

Comment: Thread1: Processing Item - 123, priority - 8,
Thread2: Processing Item - 125, priority - 5,
Thread1: Processing Item - 126, priority - 3,
Thread2: Processing Item - 124, priority - 2,

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a flag which will define which thread should process next item.

```
public class itemsImpl {

    private static PriorityBlockingQueue<Items> priorityQueue;
    private volatile boolean flag = false; //flag to define which thread should proceed

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        priorityQueue = new PriorityBlockingQueue<Items>();

        priorityQueue.add(new Items( 123,"item1", 8));
        priorityQueue.add(new Items( 124, "item2", 2));
        priorityQueue.add(new Items( 125, "item3", 5));
        priorityQueue.add(new Items( 126,"item4", 3));

        itemsImpl impl = new itemsImpl();

        Thread t1 = new Thread( new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                try {
                    impl.pollQueue(Thread.currentThread().getName(), false);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }});

        Thread t2 = new Thread( () -> {
            try {
                impl.pollQueue(Thread.currentThread().getName(), true);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } );
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }


    private void pollQueue(String name, boolean expected) throws InterruptedException {
        while(priorityQueue.size()>0) {
            synchronized(this) {
                while (flag != expected) { // thread is waiting for its turn
                    this.wait();
                }
                Items i = priorityQueue.take(); //You need to either use blocking take() or check that item is not null
                System.out.println(name +": Items Processsing - " + i.getItemID() + ", priority - " + i.getPriority());
                flag = !expected;
                this.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }
}
```